# Roll back to previous version of windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, system-recovery

My gf was on my PC and was trying to install a student version of office, but instead she installed a student version of windows 10...on top of my windows 10 pro.

Everything seems to be working the same, however, I get the activation notification now. I used my legit copy of windows 8.1 and did the free upgrade to windows 10 a while ago. I tried entering my windows 8 key, but it is not working.

I went to windows 10 recovery utility and tried the roll back to previous version, but it is saying the files needed to roll back have been deleted.

I haven't deleted anything yet. I did notice a `Windows.old` folder on my C drive. I assume it is looking for that. As far as I can tell it is all intact.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to reinstall the same version of Windows 10 you had installed the current version cannot be activated with the license key you have.  In this case the Windows.old cannot be used to revert to your previous installation

Answer (score 0):

That's should be. Since the free upgrade only support like to like, Pro to Pro, Home to Home

And for 10 days after you upgrade to Windows 10, you’ll be able to go back to your previous version of Windows. However, the process of yours is not belong to version upgrade.

The action for you is re-installing the Windows 10 Pro, it will be automatically activated during your setup.

According to Microsoft official information:

If you activated a free upgrade to Windows 10 or bought and activated Windows 10 from the Microsoft Store, you have a digital license for your device. This means you can reinstall the same edition of Windows 10 that your device has a digital license for without entering a product key. During reinstallation, if you’re asked to enter a product key, you can skip this step. Windows 10 will automatically activate online after the installation is complete.